# How do I locate resource files in a Spring Boot project deployed to Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My Spring Boot project contains an XML file within the src/main/resources folder, which is the common location for such a file.

Running locally and also on Pivotal CloudFoundary, I am able to locate the file and read it in, but on Beanstalk the process results in an empty file.

Code to locate and read file:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/myFile.xml");
LOG.info("File location: " + url.toString());
```

Resulting log entry:

```
File location: jar:file:/var/app/current/application.jar!/WEB-INF/classes!/myFile.xml
```

When I SSH into EC2 instance, I can find the jar in the specified directory.

Do I need to configure Maven to move this file somewhere?

**UPDATE**

I've since realized that I need to treat this file as in InputStream as it's packaged within the jar.

I'm now using the following code which results in the follow errors:

```
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(new ClassPathResource("myFile.xml").getInputStream(), myFile);

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openOutputStream(FileUtils.java:345) ~[commons-io-2.5.jar:2.5]
```

and

```
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(new ClassPathResource("classpath:myFile.xml").getInputStream(), myFile);


java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [classpath:myFile.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How does your pom.xml look like? Maybe there is a resource-filter active?
In a spring application you could use `File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:myFile.xml");` to read a resource file.

Could you check the result by using `ResourceUtils`?

Here the link to the api-documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ResourceUtils.html#getFile-java.lang.String-